# Java try - finally design

Tags: try-finally

With JDK 6 and below I seen many code snippets with try - finally blocks like below.

```
private void doSomething() throws IOException {
    FileReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new FileReader("someFile");
        .....
    } finally {
        if(reader != null){
            reader.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Why are initializing reader to null and then assign it in try block. Would below template better (Wondering if I am missing anything)? My reasons... we avoiding null check in finally block and if reader failed to initialized then I don't to have to do anything else.

```
private void doSomething() throws IOException {
    FileReader reader = new FileReader("someFile");
    try {

        .....
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really! If the constructor throws exception, the rest of the method nothing to do anyway. See throws clause?

Answer (score 0):

Alone, having the declaration poses no problem, but as you add more resources that need closing, you start getting a bunch of unclosed resources. Better to declare them outside as `null`, and handle closing inside with `finally`.

**Poor Implementation**

```
private void doSomething() throws IOException {
    FileReader reader = new FileReader("someFile");
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("someFile2"); //throws exception
    try {

        .....
    } finally {
        reader.close();
        writer.close();
    }
} //reader remains unclosed
```

Now we have an unclosed FileReader because another constructor threw an exception.

**Proper Implementation**

```
private void doSomething() throws IOException {
    FileReader reader = null;
    FileWriter writer = null;
    try {
        reader = new FileReader("someFile");
        writer = new FileWriter("someFile2"); //throws exception
    } finally {
        if(reader != null)
            reader.close(); //closes properly
        if(writer != null) //skipped
            writer.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not dealing with multiple resources... so this does not apply

Comment: @Stackee007 It is convention, and if down the road you decide to use two resources, you will not have to refactor your code to support it.